# Likert Scale responses placed in separate columns in CSV

Tags: r, likert

I have survey data with the typical Likert scales. however, the responses choices are in separate columns in the CSV. Could someone help me join the answer choices in the same column?

[Question: In the past 30 days to what extent has childcare been a source of stress: Choices - Not at all, Somewhat, Challenging but able to manage, Very Challenging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C56vB.png) 
It makes it difficult to conduct simple descriptive statistics e.g. count().

Any help is greatly appreciated.

In the past 30 days to what extent has childcare been a source of stress.

count(Test4R$NO_ChildCare_Stress_Last30Days)
   x freq
1  0    1
2  1   14
3 NA   41

> count(Test4R$Somewhat_ChildcareStress)
>      x freq
>   1  0    1
>   2  1   16
>   3 NA   39
>   count(Test4R$Very_challenge_ChildCare)
>      x freq
>   1  0    1
>   2  1    4
>   3 NA   51
>   count(Test4R$Challenge_ChildCare_Stress)
>      x freq
>   1  1   26
>   2 NA   30

Comment: Please try to explain exactly where you're getting stuck, e.g. are you able to import the data at all, do you have the data but can't calculate a specific answer from it, etc. Then try to come up  with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that describes the problem, at the point you're stuck.

Comment: it seems that you should `read.csv` with argument `skip = 1`. Then, edit the question with the output of `dput(df)` or if it is too big, `dput(head(df, 20))`, please.

Comment: Hi Marius, I am getting stuck in running the counts on the Likert scale. For example, I would like to compute how many selected challenging, not at all, somewhat, etc. However, since each choice is is a separate column, it is not as straightforward as I expected. I expected each choice to be a different number in the same column. E.g. 1=challenging, 2=somewhat, etc.

Comment: Hi Rui, I’ll try it. I guess the other thing I could is manually change the scores in the CSV. 1=challenging, 2=somewhat but I would prefer to use my time analyzing and interpreting the output.